# Resize behaviour of Maps in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, resize

I need to know when a map in Java enlarges. For this I need a formula to calculate a good initial capacity.

In my project I need a large map which contains large objects. Therefore, I would like to prevent a resizing of the map by specifying a suitable initial capacity. By means of reflection I have looked at the behavior of maps.

```
package com.company;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map m  = new HashMap();
        int lastCapacity = 0, currentCapacity = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100_000; i++) {
            m.put(i,i);
            currentCapacity = getHashMapCapacity(m);
            if (currentCapacity>lastCapacity){
                System.out.println(lastCapacity+" --> "+currentCapacity+" at "+i+" entries.");
                lastCapacity=currentCapacity;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getHashMapCapacity(Map m){
        int size=0;
        Field tableField = null;
        try {
            tableField = HashMap.class.getDeclaredField("table");
            tableField.setAccessible(true);
            Object[] table = (Object[]) tableField.get(m);
            size = table == null ? 0 : table.length;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return size;
    }
}
```

The output was:

0 --> 16 at 1 entries.

16 --> 32 at 13 entries.

32 --> 64 at 25 entries.

64 --> 128 at 49 entries.

128 --> 256 at 97 entries.

256 --> 512 at 193 entries.

512 --> 1024 at 385 entries.

1024 --> 2048 at 769 entries.

2048 --> 4096 at 1537 entries.

4096 --> 8192 at 3073 entries.

8192 --> 16384 at 6145 entries.

16384 --> 32768 at 12289 entries.

32768 --> 65536 at 24577 entries.

65536 --> 131072 at 49153 entries.

131072 --> 262144 at 98305 entries.

Can I assume that a map always behaves that way? Are there any differences between Java 7 and Java 8?

Comment: As some general advice, Java's map classes are already fairly optimized with regard to initial capacity and resizing.  So, most of the time, you are probably safe just going with whatever those defaults are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to check out this sort of behaviour is to look at the openjdk source. It's all freely available and relatively easy to read.

In this case, checking [HashMap](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java), you will see there are some extensive implementation notes that explains how sizing works, what load factor is used as a threshold (which is driving the behaviour you are seeing), and even how the decision is made whether to use trees for the bin. Read through that and come back if it's not clear.

The code is pretty well optimised with expansion a very cheap operation. I suggest using a profile to get some evidence that the performance issue are related to expansion before you do any tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation:

The expected number of entries in the map and its load factor should be taken into account when setting its initial capacity, so as to minimize the number of rehash operations. **If the initial capacity is greater than the maximum number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash operations will ever occur.**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess I missed something in the documentation. 
The recommended load factor is 0.75. 
So the formula is capacity=entries/0.75